# ¿Por qué mi código no se ejecuta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Lo que trato de hacer es tener mis 2 atributos de manera privada, los cuales son el numero1 y el numero2 para así hacer sus métodos set y get y con los get poder poder acceder a dichos atributos y hacer la suma de ambos números, pero no se que estaré haciendo mal que mi código no se ejecuta.

```
class Operaciones:
     def __init__(self, numero1, numero2):
         self.__numero1 = numero1
         self.__numero2 = numero2

     def getNumero1(self):
         return self.__numero1

     def setNumero1(self, numero1):
         self.__numero1 = numero1

     def getNumero2(self):
         return self.__numero2

     def setNumero2(self, numero2):
         self.__numero2 = numero2

    def sumar(self):
         suma = self.getNumero1 + self.getNumero2
         return suma

 operacion = Operaciones(5, 10)
 print(operacion.sumar())
```

En consola obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es causado porque no puedes sumar los métodos(funciones) sino los resultados de esos métodos, la solución es:

```
suma = self.getNumero1() + self.getNumero2()
```

Pero yendo más alla de la pregunta hay varios errores en tu planteamiento:

- En python no existen atributos privados(para mayor información lee esta [publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555932/public-or-private-attribute-in-python-what-is-the-best-way), el `__` solo genera una ofuscación del nombre de la variable.
- La forma de implementar el concepto de *getters* y *setters* en python es a traves de [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Considerando lo anterior la solución es:

```py
class Operaciones:
    def __init__(self, numero1, numero2):
        self.__numero1 = numero1
        self.__numero2 = numero2

    @property
    def numero1(self):
        return self.__numero1

    @numero1.setter
    def numero1(self, numero1):
        self.__numero1 = numero1

    @property
    def numero2(self):
        return self.__numero2

    @numero2.setter
    def numero2(self, numero2):
        self.__numero2 = numero2

    def sumar(self):
        suma = self.numero1 + self.numero2
        return suma


if __name__ == "__main__":
    operacion = Operaciones(5, 10)
    print(operacion.sumar())
    operacion.numero1 = 12
    operacion.numero2 = 15
    print(operacion.sumar())
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, te comento que estuve viendo un curso de python y tal como en Java es como explicaron los sets y gets, de igual manera tratare de buscar mas info al respecto, y solo una duda mas, para que sirve el if __name__ etc?

Comment: @EduardoHerrera Lee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: @EduardoHerrera Si en el curso se implementan los getters and setters en python como en java entonces yo dejaria ese curso.

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tus comentarios, tomare en cuenta lo del curso, gracias